# Create a ADF Dataset to load multiple csv files (same format) from the Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

I try to create a dataset containing multiple csv files from the Blob. In the file path of dataset setting: I create a parameter - @dataset().FolderName and add FolderName in the Parameters.

[image]

[image]

I leave file (from File Path) empty as I want to grab all files in the folder. However, there is no data when I preview data. Is there anything missing? Thank you

Comment: When you hardcode your folder path, you can see the data? BTW, what's your expected? I'm not sure what do you want to do.

Comment: I cannot view the data, the output shows no data. What I expect is to view the data from all files (append them together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it on my side and it can work fine.

1. add `FolderName` parameter
   [image]
2. preview data
   [image]

If you want to merge all csv files in Data Flow, you can do this:

1.output to single file
[image]

2.set Single partition
[image]